# My UV mapping changes when switching from edit mode to object mode

Tags: texturing, uv, edit-mode, uv-image-editor, object-mode

I'm trying to create a bottle with a label I made in illustrator. I exported the Label as a Png, and then wrapped it around a section of the bottle. I really like how it looks in edit mode, but when I switch to object mode, it warps and looks different. Anyone know why?[image: Object Mode]

[image: Edit Mode]

[image: Object Mode]

[image: Edit Mode]

Comment: My first thought might be non-uniform scale - try selecting the object in object mode, then press Ctrl+A and select "Scale"

Comment: Looks like Subsurf modifier on the mesh object. When switching to object mode its effect becomes visible due to setup you have. No general solution to that, in some cases just add a loopcut into area without any ones (like you have in the bottom of the label), or can be necessary to use another approach to modeling or unwrapping